# Is .Net Map/Reduce Streaming Still Supported in HDinsight 3.5?

Tags: c#, python, .net, azure, azure-hdinsight

I am new to Microsoft Azure and i am planing to use HDinsight 3.5 which is the latest version.

HDinsight 3.5 supports Ubuntu 16 only as an operating system. I found articles about Python Streaming but not C#/.Net .

Is there any way to write Map and Reduce classes in C# and submit the job to HDinsight 3.5 Cluster and not worry about deprecation issues?

Comment: C# streaming is only supported by the Windows-based clusters. HDInsight 3.5 is Linux-based.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
It just sounded counter intuitive that Microsoft uses technologies that doesn't support .Net framework. It's now clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, @JonathanGao 's said is partly correct. Considering to C# for cross platform, there are two runtimes for C# which you can use on Linux: [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) & [.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core). The Map/Reduce programs for Hadoop Streaming are based on console application with standard I/O for pipeline. You can completely create Map/Reduce programs in C# for Mono/.NET Core.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , But does Linux based Clusters in azure have Mono/.Net Core ?